# How can I turn an object into an array (Symfony)?

Tags: arrays, symfony, object, oop, doctrine-orm

This is how I create my array `fields`:

```
public function index($slug, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
  {
    $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
    $fields =  (array) $page;
    return $this->render('mypage.html.twig', ['page' => $page, 'fields' => $fields]);
  }
```

The output is:

```
array:3 [▼
  "\x00App\Entity\Pages\x00id" => 3
  "\x00App\Entity\Pages\x00name" => "cat"
  "\x00App\Entity\Pages\x00color" => ""
]
```

But I actually need this result:

```
array:3 [▼
  "id" => 3
  "name" => "cat"
  "color" => ""
]
```

---

According to the suggestions I made this change:

```
public function index($slug, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
  {
    $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
    $fields =  get_object_vars($page);
    return $this->render('mypage.html.twig', ['page' => $page, 'fields' => $fields]);
  }
```

But this outputs me an empty array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine entity object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158549/doctrine-entity-object-to-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PHP object to associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array)

Comment: Passing both your object and serialized object to your Twig template feels a bit unnecessary. To prevent a [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please explain why you need this.

Comment: @StephanVierkant It is because it was a way I could finally solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476565/how-can-i-get-all-fields-of-a-mysql-table-with-twig-symfony?noredirect=1#comment93823988_53476565

Comment: @StephanVierkant I could not loop through object properties. But through array I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

**1. Use `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`** instead of `findOneBy()`

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(Pages:class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

(stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913902/1405981))

**2. Use a Serializer**

Use the [Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) or [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) to serialize your entity object.

Comment: Worked with serializer! `$serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new JsonEncoder()));$fields =  $serializer->serialize($page, 'json');`